# Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I ran the Rails server and, when trying to view my page on my localhost, I see this error:

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The weird thing is that a week ago this page was displaying and now it is not, so I don't understand what changed.

Comment: Is this production or development? By default, a rails server starts on port 3000. Try using that.

Comment: 5432 is the PostgreSQL default... Is your database running?

Comment: @JustinWood i am using http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra database is not running. I havent created any yet.

Comment: I think you have to create a database to connect to your Rails app...

Comment: In my case, postgres wasn't running for some reason :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 5432 port error is probably indicating that Rails is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database that hasn't yet been created or isn't running.

Check to make sure your `config\database.yml` file is accurate and run the following command:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: It was a problem with postgres as you mentioned. Changed the application.yml file details and used sqlite3 on development.
Thanks!